# System of equation from function containing summation!

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

A function is given by $Q(p,q)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(p \cdot t_i+q-y_i)^2$. I found the 2 partial derivatives to be

1. $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial p}=2 \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n}(p \cdot t_i+q-y_i)t_i$
2. $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial q}=2 \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n}(p \cdot t_i+q-y_i)$

Which I think are correct. Now I have to show that  $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial p}=0$ $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial q}=0$ can be written as a linear system of equations

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}t_i^2p+\sum_{i=1}^{n}t_iq=\sum_{i=1}^{n}t_iy_i$

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}t_ip+nq=\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i$

I have absolutely no idea on how to show this and I am sure of the fact that it is a simple observation regarding the partiel derivatives.

Any Help Is Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To make things easier to track you can rename a few things

\begin{align}
A &= \sum_{i=1}^n t_i^2 \\
B &= \sum_{i=1}^n t_i \\
C &= \sum_{i=1}^n t_i y_i \\
D &= \sum_{i=1}^n y_i \\
\end{align}

And you will end up with

\begin{align}
Ap + Bq &=C \\
Bp + nq &= D 
\end{align}

And from here is just a few steps, e.g. multiplying the first equation by $B$ and the second by $A$ you get

\begin{align}
ABp + B^2q &=CB \\
ABp + Anq &= AD 
\end{align}

now subtract the second from the first

$$
(B^2 - An)q = CB - AD ~~~\Rightarrow~~~ q = \frac{CB - AD}{B^2 - An}
$$

I will leave the other one to you

Comment: The other one so $p$? Is that all that is required in this question and then I am done? Was confused on how to "show" that it is a linear system of equations. Is this just it?

Comment: @bymathformath Yes, the other one is $p$, and yes the first pair of equations shows that is a linear system

Comment: So $p=CB-AD$ right since they just cancel out $ABp$

Comment: nevermind it is not correct I am stuck.

Comment: https://ibb.co/9T0FzPD   - is this correct

Comment: @bymathformath The value of $q$ is known, replace that in the first equation $p = (C - Bq)/A$, and you will find the value of $p$. And that's it

Comment: I see, I get these 2 when i replace them in https://ibb.co/MNMPLxw